# Join Two Select Queries having where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 2 select queries one is for display all table columns and second is for display sum of column 5.

I want to join the result of all these statements into one table in order to make my stored procedure but the resulting table shall have 7 different columns.

```
select sum(Sale_price) as sum_of_saleprice from StockDetail
```

[image: RESULT OF 1ST QUERY]

```
select * from StockDetail
```

[image: RESULT OF 2ND QUERY]

I want both in same table

Comment: So you want every row to have the same count associated with it?

Comment: SELECT SUM(SD.sale_price) AS SumOfSalePrice , SD.* 
FROM stockdetail SD;

Comment: yes i want one data table having All rows from my table and sum of column 3 as sum in another column

Comment: Try my query in above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include the sum as a column with every row try this..

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT SUM(SALE_PRICE) FROM StockDetail) AS sum_of_saleprice
FROM StockDetail
```

If you want one record to represent the totals of the other records try this..

```
SELECT 
    Item_ID,
    Item_Name,
    Last_Stock,
    Cost_Price,
    Sale_Price,
    Stock_Quantiy
FROM StockDetail
UNION
SELECT
    -1,
    'All Items',
    MAX(Last_Stock),
    SUM(ISNULL(Cost_Price, 0)), 
    SUM(Sale_Price),
    SUM(Stock_Quantity)
FROM StockDetail
```

Comment: if it will give only 1 row for sum_of_saleprice , more useful for me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add the count to every row try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM stockdetail, (SELECT SUM(sale_price) FROM stockdetail) AS cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use a UNION ALL:
Here is a quick example Table1 has regional sales and the goal is to both show provincial sales along with a subtotal in the same query.
Quick example:

```
SELECT Region, Sales FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'All Regions', SUM(Sales) FROM TABLE1
```